# SharePoint 2010 Page/List/Listform Setup with Significant Permissions Restrictions

Tags: 2010, list, permissions, list-form

We have SharePoint 2010. I am new to the program and am not sure of the best way to set up a new page and/or list/listform given the permissions restrictions we need.

Users will need to submit a series of confidential responses each month to approximately 10 questions. These answers cannot be changed once they have been submitted. Obviously, this means that we will need to limit what can be added and by whom. Each user can only submit answers for himself or herself, so I presume it must be based upon his or her login information.

Each user will need to be able to see what he or she has already submitted for the year for each question, plus a running total of their own data, but cannot change what was already submitted. Also, users can only see their own answers.

There will be approximately 175 users (the user list will change frequently) and approximately 5 superusers who can see the totals for the group and the totals per user, and who can also download the totals spreadsheet.

What is the best way to set up something like this? How can we have users only see their own data and only submit for themselves? How can we make the user maintenance relatively simple, given that permissions cannot inherit from the parent site?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get something like this up and going pretty quickly.

Create two lists and a workflow
Answer Submission List

All users have permissions to submit answers

> Advanced Settings
> Read Access - Read items that were created by the user
>
> Create and Edit Access - Create items and edit items that were created by user

Compiled Answers List

> Columns match the Answer Submission List
>
> All users have permissions to read answers
>
> Advanced Settings
>
> Read Access - Read items that were created by the user
>
> Create and Edit Access - None

Workflow

Copy the submissions from "Answer" list to the "Compiled" list.  It's your call if you want it to execute as soon as an item is created (meaning they can't change it), or allow them to run the workflow on demand once they are good with the answer.   You will probably also want to delete the item from the "Answer" list.